# Are there any brands of mustard powder (flour) that are kosher for Passover for Sephardim?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover, kitniyos-semigrain-legume, product-recommendation, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern

Prepared mustard (containing vinegar and the like) is certainly not kosher for Passover.  According to Ashkenazic practice, the mustard plant itself is included in "kitniot" and prohibited on Passover.

For Sephardic Jews, however, is there a brand of plain mustard powder that can be assumed to be free of wheat/barley/spelt/oat/rye and therefore kosher for Passover?

Comment: I recall knowing some English Ashkenazim who would use a particular British brand of mustard powder on Pesach.

Comment: That's fascinating.  Traditional "prepared English mustard" contains wheat flour; but I suppose some Ashkenazim didn't have the custom that mustard seed itself was kitniyos.  With these customs, you never know.  My guess is if they used a brand, it was probably the Coleman's mustard powder (ingredients: mustard powder), it's under the London Beth Din for year-round.

Answer (score 2):

[This site](http://www.kashrut.org/pesach/) has a list of things sefardim may use on Pesach But I warn you the Rabbi involved is  a controversial figure in The Sefardic community so double check with your own Sefardic Rabbi agrees with his list.

Answer (score 1):

Guldens Spicy Brown Mustard should be ok for Sephardim.  However, ask your Halchick Authority.
Here are some others: Annie's naturals Organic Dijon Mustard, Gold's Deli mustard

I could try and find more, but that gives you some.  The key is that the Vinegar is made from Corn. So for Sephardim it would be ok.

Not all poskim hold this, so please ask your Halachik authority.

Comment: There's still an issue of cross-contamination from chametz if it doesn't have a pesachdik hechsher

Answer (score 1):

French mustard is generally made with white wine vinegar. Because a plurality of French Jews are Sephardic and mustard is the standard condiment to put on meat in France, most brands that produce kosher mustard produce a kosher le pesach version. You can purchase both Dijon mustard and whole grain (referred to as "moutarde a l'ancienne") with good KLP certification.

Here is a link to Shnieder's, a good frum French brand (they produce, for example, cholov yisrael and parve versions of nutella). The dijon mustard is "chalak beit yosef" certified for passover. https://www.aucacher.com/sauces/29481-Moutarde-dijon-370g-31-838948003759.html

No need to try to find KLP-certified mustard powder and prepare your own; the mustard listed here goes for 1.90€. Even with shipping that's not too bad.